# SQL Functions at magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql, orm

I need to write a question use **Magento ORM** applying **functions** at condition like this:

> SELECT * WHERE REPLACE(street, ' ', '') = 'Streetac'.

I try using regular expressions but I have problem with case sensitive.

I need a function like this: addExpressionFieldToSelect, but I need to use this function at condition.

In that the query return all this cases.

> 'House 12' = 'hOuse 12' = 'house       12   ' = HouSe   12  '

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do.. You want that request like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition = mycondition" where mycondition can be "House 12" or "hOuse 12" or "house 12" or "HouSe 12".. ?

Comment: The query must return that the field with this values this cases: 'House 12' = 'hOuse 12' = 'house 12 ' = HouSe   12    ' are equels.

Comment: My problem is with the withspaces if I have a lot of whitespeces at the end or between the words at the string and I need that the query were insensitive.

Comment: May be you can use UPPER() function for mysql, so all your cases 'House 12', 'hOuse 12', 'house 12 ', ' HouSe 12 '  will be change to 'HOUSE 12' for the comparison (and so bypass the case). For the whitespaces, you can use your replace.

Comment: Yes I try this but the problem its that magento ORM dont allow to apply sql functions at sql conditions. The query its envolved into ` ` for this reason the UPPER() function when magento excecute the sql query the condition its excecuted into: "UPPER(`fieldname`)".
I need to do this with magento ORM I not allowed to use a query directly .